# Forma mais segura de conexão entre Android e Arduino

Tags: android, arduino, conexão

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que se comunica com Arduino (Uno). Utilizei dois modos para comunicar até agora, via USB(usei as bibliotecas usb-serial-for-android e Physicaloid) e Bluetooth.

O envio e recebimento de dados via Bluetooth era um pouco lento e algumas vezes a informação simplesmente não era enviada ou recebida. Na comunicação via USB o envio de dados era bem rápido, mas mesmo assim, algumas vezes a conexão não abre e é muito aleatório. Executo o aplicativo e a conexão USB não abre, fecho o aplicativo, executo novamente e a conexão abre. Ainda não tentei conexão via WIFI.

Qual a forma ideal e mais segura de realizar conexão com Arduino?

Comment: Pelas informações todas os modos usados apresentam problemas, para mim leva a crer que o problema seja da própria programação (de ambos os lados) ou do próprio dispositivo (arduino ou no Android) utilizado, mas não sua forma de conexão. Eu sempre utilizei por Wifi e por Ethernet, que numa mesma rede pode ser acessado pelo Wifi. Já tive problemas de lentidão e de demora para execução de tarefas, isso era principalmente falta de memoria e muitas conexões simultâneas. Cada caso é um caso, mas se três modos usados apresentam problemas... acho que o problema não é este.

Comment: Entendi, vou revisar o código, realmente pode ter alguma coisa errada, obrigado pela resposta!